# What is the difference between "My PC needs repairing" and "I have to get my PC repaired"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, difference

If I want to say that my PC needs/has to be repaired by someone else, could I use the sentences below?

> 1. My PC needs repairing.
> 2. I have to get my PC repaired.

If not, then what is the difference between 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"My PC needs repairing." can be used. It sounds a bit informal. You could also say "My PC needs repair."
 Those could be used whether you will have someone else do the repair, or do it yourself.

I have to get my PC repaired." is also usable. The focus there is on your need rather than the computer's need, and "get my PC repaired" means you will have someone else do the repair.